# Hibernate criteria distinct on all columns

Tags: hibernate

I want to create a Hibernate Criteria that selects distinct based on all returned columns in a query.  The best that I can do is to create a ProjectionList and add each column to the list which seems very verbose compared to SQL.

pseudo-SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent.*, child.name
  FROM parent INNER JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
 WHERE child.name = 'Chris'
```

Note I want to do this on the database not using a ResultTransformer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: JPQL (and the the criteria API) should allow the distinct keyword.  Is the trouble that you're trying to also select child.name?  The following would be the JPQL query.  I don't have my IDE up to look up the criteria builder representation.  `SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Parent p JOIN p.children c WHERE c.name = 'Chris'`